# Grails 3.1.9 with spring-security-ui plugin register fails with cannot generate an EntityKey when id is null

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I have a Grails project Version 3.1.9, in which I have installed the spring-security-core(v3.1.1) and spring-security-ui(v3.0.0.M2) plugins.

The SUI plugin has installed and I can go to the register/register page and enter details for a new user

When I click the Create Your Account button I get a
"cannot generate an EntityKey when id is null" error.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to fix this?

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot generate an EntityKey when id is null.
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityEntry.getEntityKey(EntityEntry.java:254)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultEvictEventListener.onEvict(DefaultEvictEventListener.java:95)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireEvict(SessionImpl.java:1210)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.evict(SessionImpl.java:1203)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate$8.doInHibernate(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:327)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:196)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.evict(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:325)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.discard(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:179)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.discard(GormEntity.groovy:180)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper$discard$3.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.RegistrationCode.discard(RegistrationCode.groovy)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$discard$0.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.SpringSecurityUiService.rollbackAndDiscard(SpringSecurityUiService.groovy:545)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:174)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.SpringSecurityUiService.handleException(SpringSecurityUiService.groovy:534)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.strategy.DefaultErrorsStrategy.handleException(DefaultErrorsStrategy.groovy:35)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.strategy.ErrorsStrategy$handleException.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.SpringSecurityUiService.save(SpringSecurityUiService.groovy:636)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.SpringSecurityUiService.save(SpringSecurityUiService.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:190)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.SpringSecurityUiService.$tt__register(SpringSecurityUiService.groovy:181)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.SpringSecurityUiService$_register_closure17.doCall(SpringSecurityUiService.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:96)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:93)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.SpringSecurityUiService.register(SpringSecurityUiService.groovy)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.strategy.DefaultRegistrationCodeStrategy.register(DefaultRegistrationCodeStrategy.groovy:40)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.strategy.RegistrationCodeStrategy$register$0.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.RegisterController.register(RegisterController.groovy:55)
at hvpermit.RegisterController.register(RegisterController.groovy)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.RegisterController.register(RegisterController.groovy)
at hvpermit.RegisterController.register(RegisterController.groovy)
... 84 common frames omitted
```

Comment: i was not able to reproduce this problem. can you provide your spring security configuration and domain class for your User?

Comment: I turned on sql logging and discovered the real problem. It was trying to use a non existent sequence for the ID field.  I have now created the sequence and the issue is fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to please give better details of how use solved the problem?Maybe update the question with an answer showing what non existent sequence it was trying to use for the ID field, and how you created the sequence to fix the issue? it will really help...

Comment: Turn on SQL logging. You will see where the query tries to use a sequence like hibernate_seq. Create this sequence in the db and you should be good to go

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same error when trying to implement a forgot password interface using spring-security-ui.

I hadn't realized it but spring-security-ui is expecting that the following table exists:

```sql
create table if not exists registration_code
(
    id           bigint auto_increment primary key,
    username     varchar(255) not null,
    token        varchar(255) not null,
    date_created datetime     not null
);
```

Without this table the forgot password was throwing the error `IllegalStateException: cannot generate an EntityKey when id is null.`. It seems fairly likely that this is what you were running into as well with user registration.

Hope this helps someone else.. or me in the future :)